# Create provably fair number with first 4 bytes of byte array C#

Tags: c#, numbers

I am doing some work in college on provably fair number generation, and the method I decided on was to hash (sha512) a password with a salt and then get the first 4 bytes.

I have the first part handled but I am unsure of how to get the first 4, and at the moment I am using 
        Convert.ToInt32(bytearray);

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: if you have a byte array already, what do you need the elements are available?  Do you need it truncating?

Answer (score 2):

To convert the first 4 bytes of a `byte[]` to an integer use the [BitConverter.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 0); // 0 is the start index
```

---

`Convert.ToInt32(bytearray);` is not an compile time error, but it will call the generic [Convert.ToInt32(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which will probably not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks for this, thats really helpful however how do I limit it to the first 4 bytes as it is currently a lot longer.

Comment: ToInt32 **always** uses 4 bytes since the result should be a 32-bit integer.

Comment: The numbers are all coming out very predictably often being around the same points. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, but that might be a problem of your algorithm and is not related to getting the first 4 bytes from a byte[].